# php home posts system using Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code to get there posts on their profile

```
<?php
$getposts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos_content WHERE username ='$username' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10") or die(mysql_error());
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getposts)) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $video_title = $row['video_title']; 
            $video_url = $row['video_url']; 
            $date_posted = $row['date_posted'];
            $added_by = $row['username'];

            $get_user_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$added_by'");
            $get_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_user_info);
            $profilepic_info = $get_info['profile_pic'];
                if ($profilepic_info == "") {
                    $profilepic_info = "./image/default_pic.jpg";
                }
                else
                {
                    $profilepic_info = "./userdata/profile_pics/".$profilepic_info;
                }
?>
```

My sql user table is like this

```
[id,username,followers,following,account_active]
```

-> My following and followers columns are arrays with comma separated values.

My sql posts table is like this

```
[id,username,video_title,video_url,date_posted,removed]
```

I want to display posts of people whom a user(i mean a logged in user) is following on his/her home page.

can anyone suggest me some solution ?

Thanks.

I tried this code

```
<?php
  $followingArray = "";
  $countFollowing = "";
  $followingArray12 = "";
  $selectFollowingQuery = mysql_query("SELECT following FROM users WHERE username = '$user' ");
  $followingRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectFollowingQuery);
  $followingArray = $followingRow['following'];

  if ($followingArray != "") {
    $followingArray = explode(",","$followingArray");
    $countFollowing = count($followingArray);
    $followingArray12 = array_slice($followingArray, 0, 12);

$getposts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos_content WHERE username ='$username' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10") or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getposts)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $video_title = $row['video_title'];   
        $video_url = $row['video_url'];   
        $date_posted = $row['date_posted'];
        $added_by = $row['username'];

        $get_user_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$added_by'");
        $get_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_user_info);
        $profilepic_info = $get_info['profile_pic'];
            if ($profilepic_info == "") {
                $profilepic_info = "./image/default_pic.jpg";
            }
            else
            {
                $profilepic_info = "./userdata/profile_pics/".$profilepic_info;
            }
       }
            if (in_array($username, $followingArray) {
                echo '(posts)'; /*html to echo those posts, its a very long chain of divs, that is the reason i didn't include that code.*/
            }
            else{
            echo ''; /*nothing*/
            }

   }
?>
```

Comment: Did you at least tried some code you might want to share?

Comment: i included the code which i tried, please check it and suggest something, its not working actually.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would suggest splitting your `users` table into 3 tables.

```
users : [id,username,account_active]

followers : [id,followerId]

following : [id,followingId]
```

This will prevent columns with comma-separated values, and make your problems much simpler.

From there its easy:

```
SELECT *
FROM   posts
WHERE  id IN (
    SELECT followerId
    FROM followers
    WHERE id = $userID
);
```

etc..